# Ken Burns Effect. - Software Recommendations

Tags: software-recommendation, photos

I am using Windows 7 and trying to find a right application to get advanced features of the "[Ken Burns effect]", like pan and zoom. Unfortunately Photostory version in Windows 7 is not able to get effects. I have access to Photoshop in other computer

Comment: You can try the freely-available Lightworks, but beware - this is a cinema-grade piece of software and comes with a steep learning curve. Do you have to use Windows 7? If you have access to a Linux or Mac system, there are plenty of options. Windows... not so much.

Answer (score 1):

Any software with keyframe support can do this.  [This answer](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/8651/final-cut-pro-x-ken-burn-effect-on-video-clips-with-out-cutting-clip-apart) provides a rough walkthrough of how you can accomplish the look you are describing with just keyframes and positioning/scale keyframes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a free and open-source option, [ffDiaporama](http://ffdiaporama.tuxfamily.org/) is quite good. It's mainly geared towards making photo slideshows (but allows for video too), which are rendered into a video file.

It supports doing Ken Burns effects (and any other transforms, using keyframes), and works pretty similarly to other video editors in that regard.

The UI may be a bit non-intuitive if you havn't used keyframeable video editors before, but it's pretty easy to use.

There's a video on how to do Ken Burns -style pan and zooms [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x0QwiZmXzvI).

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Lightworks' free version](http://lightworks.wikidot.com/zooming-panning-and-ken-burns-effect).